# FreeBSD telnet does not take root login

Tags: freebsd, users, telnet

I have just installed FreeBSD 8.1 as a VMWare host and can establish ipv4 connectivity to the instance and `telnet` through the [virtual console](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/consoles.html). I have also uncommented the `/etc/inetd.conf` lines

```
telnet  stream  tcp nowait  root    /usr/libexec/telnetd    telnetd
telnet  stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/libexec/telnetd    telnetd
```

When I login without telnet via new [virtual console](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/consoles.html) terminals  with `login: root` and `password` the default of empty, the login is accepted.

However, when I login remotely via telnet, I am prompted exactly the same as before, except for an additional first line that reads `(freebsd.westell.com) (pts/0)`. I use the same login of `root` as before but get `login incorrect` message. What is missing here to successfully login to a telnet session?

For example, `root` is the only [user](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/users.html) currently, am I missing `adduser`?

---

Alternatively, if someone can show how to configure SSH and login remotely on FreeBSD 8.1,  in `<` 5 easy steps which spell out exactly which configuration files and lines need to be edited, I'll take that. I haven't found this in their [documentation](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/securing-freebsd.html).

Comment: [Don't do this.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/72116/2) Just because the first answer didn't satisfy you is no reason to vandalize your own question. Don't be so impatient!

Comment: @Gilles maybe you're right, but I am no network or UNIX engineer and with all the UNIX gurus here I find it surprising that I have only received 1 answer to a seemingly basic question. 
Is this not in some tutorial or documentation page I missed?

Comment: it appears to have something to do with nonexistence of /dev/vtyp0, but the file can't be created anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Check the file /etc/ttys which contains list of terminals. Only those marked "secure" will allow root to login. By default this is the console and all virtual terminals. Pseudo terminals do not allow root login.

Also, in this day and age, where security is a big concern, may I ask why you are still using an unsecure protocol like telnet and not ssh ?

(edit) thanks to James, I realized I glossed over the FreeBSD and suggested the solution I always used and took for granted on Linux. Unless you have the PAM security add-on's enabled, you will not have this file. Instead, use the file mentioned by James on the answer above.

Comment: I am building a practice lab environment to study for the CCNA, and the most versatile and lightweight OS I know of is FreeBSD. If there's an equivalent OS that's more user-friendly, please let me know since working with the FreeBSD terminal without the scrolling and copy-paste is really a hassle.

Comment: Any reason not to SSH to that FreeBSD server and then invoke `su - toor` ?

Comment: @Hennes I was unaware of toor command. I am running telnet from Windwos.

Comment: I have 5 in /etc/securetity, audit_class, audit_control, audit_event, audit_user, audit_warn. There is no `/etc/securetty` on my FreeBSD installation.

Comment: Why not use SSH (with a client like PuTTY on Windows) instead of the insecure telnet?

Comment: Because this is a lab environment. The intent is learning and simplicity. I have been using telnet via PuTTY already with every other host OS and it would appear simpler to do the same here. Why can't telnet be used here and why are the comments `>` direct answers?

Comment: Please see the modified answer above. Also, ssh vs. telnet discusssion: please don't dismiss the ssh sughgestions. Even when you are learning, it is best to do the learning, with tools used in the professional world instead of learning in vacuum. And setup of ssh is not a big matter after all.

Comment: What "answer above"?

Comment: @M.Kjorling .. the answer you are adding comments to. That's what I was referencing...

Comment: I was referring to when you wrote at the end of your answer "Instead, use the file mentioned by James on the answer above.". I now see that it was actually only visible in the edit history of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use `telnetd`, FreeBSD has `sshd` out-of-the-box and [it's easy to enable it](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/openssh.html) (paragraph 15.10.2 gives you 2 simple steps). Root login by default disabled in `sshd` for security reasons, but if you just building testing environment, not facing outer world, you can enable it with `PermitRootLogin yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, but shouldn't ever be done on anything but a private network where you're the only possible user, because it will open root to be hacked through automated attempts and also show its password in plaintext on your network.

Add lines like this to `/etc/ttys`

```
pts/? none network off secure
```

where `?` is a decimal number from 0 upwards.  As long as the pty you get is within that range, now you can present the root login and password and login successfully.

Please be warned again that this is unwise.  The ssh suggested above is a wiser answer.

Comment: FreeBSD does not use `pts` lines in `/etc/ttys`.  Per [the man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ttys): "The file ttys contains information that is used by various routines to initialize and control the use of terminal special files.  Pseudo-terminals (see pts(4)) are not listed."

Comment: Thank you for the intended clarification, which I hope is what it was intended as, and not as a gotcha.

Please permit me to add that I have verified the behavior on the latest RELEASE version of FreeBSD, as the instructions for this website say I should.  Did you?

I found the original question while Googling around to see if there was a way to be this permissive.

Is there an ethical problem with doing this on someone else's machine?  Possibly.  I did it on my own machine.  It is true that system configuration does not add these lines.  But if added by the administrator, they work.

Comment: In the case of a private machine on a private network, the passwords and other security are probably only there to keep you from stumbling over your own feet unintentionally, and are about as robustly needed as sudo on most Linuxes.  However, *BSD is supposed to be a little more secure than Linux.  And it is.  A little.  I would push back that BSD should actively disallow this behavior to live up to this reputation when exposed to untrusted users.

Comment: Please [edit] and add any additional information to your answer, and *not* in the comments. The comments are generally ephemeral in nature and tend to get deleted after time. They are generally used to request clarification for you to [edit] into your answer. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/280335) to [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/280335), for additional clarification, if required.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).